# Rails 'generate' command returning an error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

i'm a new in rails, and have to support new project, so sorry for this stupid question.

I need to create new page on main site, not in admin panel, trying  `rails generate controller Impulse index` as in tutorial, but got error:

`/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/runtime.rb:80:in 'rescue in block (2 levels) in require': There was an error while trying to load the gem 'activeadmin'. (Bundler::GemRequireError)`

full error here

```
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/runtime.rb:80:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in require': There was an error while trying to load the gem 'activeadmin'. (Bundler::GemRequireError)
        from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler.rb:99:in `require'
        from /home/deploy/20171102/staytrue/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:141:in `require'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:141:in `require_application_and_environment!'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:128:in `generate_or_destroy'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:50:in `generate'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:8:in `require'
        from bin/rails:8:in `<main>'
```

Comment: try `bundle exec rails generate ...` also `bundle install`. In general - your code (maybe one of initializers) is trying to use gem `activeadmin` which is not present.

Comment: bundles are installed, and i can deploy app to the server with "bundle exec cap production deploy"

Comment: Are you sure?! The error strongly indicates something is *not* installed.

Comment: Yes, i can change existing pages, and deploy to server

Comment: What is the result of `bundle show | grep activeadmin`  ?

Comment: Are you just trying to create a controller? If so, run `rails g migrate your_controller_name_here`.

Comment: @whodini9 
`* activeadmin (2.0.0.alpha 5892999)
* activeadmin_hstore_editor (0.0.5)`.          

`rails g migrate your_controller_name_here`
gives the same error
same error

Comment: follow this steps: 1-remove gemfile.lock 2- remove activeadmin gem 3- bundle install/update

Answer (score 0):

follow this steps:

1. remove gemfile.lock ( `rm Gemfile.lock` )
2. remove activeadmin gem ( `gem uninstall activeadmin` )
3. bundle install/update

for test on irb/rails c :

```
require 'activeadmin'
```